# How to configure a peer as admin peer in Hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have setup the fabric network on local machine , when I am trying to create a new channel using this command:

```
./peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /home/appinventiv/binaries/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I get this error :

```
/Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
```

and orderer debug logs shows this :

```
Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Org2MSP.Admins Org1MSP.Admins ]
```

so I guess, peer has to be the Admin to create a channel.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the environment variables to the correct values?
I'd recommend creating a .sh file and exporting everything from there, for example:

```
export CORE_PEER_ID=peer1
export CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH="./ledgers/peer1/ledger"
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH="$PWD/../fabric-ca/client/org1/admin/msp"
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=OrgMSP
export CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
export CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
export CORE_PEER_EVENTS_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7053
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH="$PWD"
```

You should set up those with your values, since I may have a different setup and then run: (With the dot in front of ./ too)

```
. ./setEnv.sh
```